# Javascript with new or not

Tags: javascript

I have the following function

```
var myInstance =  (function() {
  var privateVar = 'Test';

  function privateMethod () {
    // ...
  }

  return { // public interface
    publicMethod1: function () {
      // all private members are accesible here
        alert(privateVar);
    },
    publicMethod2: function () {
    }
  };
})();
```

what's the difference if I add a new to the function. From firebug, it seems two objects are the same. And as I understand, both should enforce the singleton pattern.

```
var myInstance =  new (function() {
  var privateVar = 'Test';

  function privateMethod () {
    // ...
  }

  return { // public interface
    publicMethod1: function () {
      // all private members are accesible here
        alert(privateVar);
    },
    publicMethod2: function () {
    }
  };
})();
```

Comment: [What the the "new" keyword in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the end result seems identical, how it got there and what it executed in is different.

The first version executes the anonymous function with `this` being in the context of the `window` object.  The second version executes the anonymous function, but `this` is in the context of a new empty object.

In the end, they both return another object(your Singleton).  It's just a slight difference in execution context.

To test this out, but an `alert(this);` right before the declaration of the `privateVar` variable.

@Tom Squires:  That's not necessarily true and is poor practice not to declare your variables.  A script with the `"use strict";` directive does cause the JS engine to complain (assuming that the engine supports `"use strict"`;