# IIFE context issues

Tags: javascript, this, iife

In the following construct:

```
(function(){

    var x = function(){
        alert('hi!');
    }

    var y = function(){
        alert("hi again!");
    }

    this.show = function(){
        alert("This is show function!");
    }

})();
```

Why does `this` refer to `window` object? Should everything inside IIFE be isolated from global scope? Are `x` and `y` functions also properties of `window` global object?

Also, even if I use put `var h = ...` at the beginning:

```
var h = (function(){

    var x = function(){
        alert('hi!');
    }

    var y = function(){
        alert("hi again!");
    }

    this.show = function(){
        alert("This is show function!");
    }

})();
```

`this` still refers to window object -- I can just call `show()` from the global scope! How come?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The global context (`window` in a browser) is the value `this` gets when there's no other value to use.

Your local variables are local (that is, not properties of `window`). They're declared inside the function with `var`.

The reason why adding `var h = (function(){...` makes no difference is because of the way you call the function. The function reference is not a property value of an object (like `something.func()`), and you don't invoke it with `.call()` or `.apply()`, so therefore this refers to the global (`window`) object. That's just the way the language is defined to act.

Answer (score 10):

@Pointy is correct, but he doesn't present the whole issue - you might be interested in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467282/javascript-with-new-or-not/6473416#6473416). The issue here is that if you aren't using the `new` keyword, you aren't instantiating an object, so there's no instance for `this` to refer to. In the absence of an instance, `this` refers to the `window` object.

In general, you don't need `this` within an IIFE, because you have direct access to any function or variable defined in the anonymous function's scope - `show()` can call `x()` and `y()` directly, so there's no need for a `this` reference. There may be a valid use case for instantiating an IIFE with `new`, but I've never come across it.

Comment: A valid case would be when you need to pass "this" within an IIFE to another object that uses it to make callbacks.

Comment: @AndroidDev, you could use local object and treat it as 'this', pass it to another object when that should access your 'this' as it's 'this' with bind() method