# "this" in self executing code

Tags: javascript, self-executing-function

Why here "this" is different for self executing code(window/globalScope), inside a object's member function?

```
foo = "Window_foo"
var myobj = {
  foo: 'Object_bar',
  func: function(){
    var self = this;
    console.log("outer this.foo " + this.foo);
    console.log("outer self.foo " + self.foo);
    (function(){
       console.log("inner this.foo " + this.foo);
       console.log("inner self.foo " + self.foo);
    }());
  }
}
myobj.func();
```

I get below output:

```
outer this.foo Object_bar
outer self.foo Object_bar
inner this.foo Window_foo
inner self.foo Object_bar
```

func is the member function of myObj object. "this" inside it must be the myObj object. Then how self executing function inside it has "this" as window object?

Comment: this belongs to the method in func(), but in a free floating function, it's global default

Comment: that is the default value for `this`.

Comment: FWIW, it's usually "immediately invoked function" rather than "self-executing function".

Comment: As a very experienced JavaScript user, I can at least agree with you that it doesn't make too much sense. The rules are consistent, and you can live with them if you know them, but they don't make much sense.

Comment: Next to the duplicate, see also [IIFE context issues](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7653757/1048572)

Answer (score 3):

Self executing functions have the window object as the value of their `this`, even if it's inside a method of your object.

Answer (score 0):

to self reference a singleton object's elements. you can declare the function after you create the object like

```
foo = "Window_foo"
var myobj = {
  foo: 'Object_bar'
}

  myobj.func: function(){
    console.log("outer myobj.foo " + myobj.foo);
    console.log("outer myobj.foo " + myobj.foo);
    (function(){
       console.log("inner myobj.foo " + myobj.foo);
       console.log("inner myobj.foo " + myobj.foo);
    }());
  }
```

Comment: In this case, he doesn't have to actually split it like that because `func` is a function that won't be executed until after `myobj` is defined. Also, side-note, your syntax is wrong here: `myobj.func: function..`

Comment: Why the comment by dandavis - "this belongs to the method in func(), but in a free floating function, it's global default", doesn't hold true for the way you have described here?

Comment: @RatneshLal In this example, he isn't using `this`, he used `myobj.foo` which will always reference whatever is stored in `myobj.foo`

Comment: Ohh my bad in noticing that, sorry. So for all anonymous self executing function "this" is MUST be window object. Correct?

Comment: atleast this is the way i know for sure. i searched finding a way to reference object itself from within a function of it, that i couldnt find. And i am currently using this to store my application wide variables that can go together. so i wont pass around tens of variables.